# Remove items in a sequence from a string Python

Tags: python, string, function, strip

Okay so I'm trying to make a function that will take a string and a sequence of items (in the form of either a list, a tuple or a string) and remove all items from that list from the string.

So far my attempt looks like this:

```
def eliminate(s, bad_characters):
    for item in bad_characters:
        s = s.strip(item)
    return s
```

However, for some reason when I try this or variations of this, it only returns either the original string or a version with only the first item in bad_characters removed.

```
>>> eliminate("foobar",["o","b"])
'foobar'
```

Is there a way to remove all items in bad_characters from the given string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the bad characters as empty strings.

```
def eliminate(s, bad_characters):
    for item in bad_characters:
        s = s.replace(item, '')
    return s
```

`strip()` doesn't work as it tries to remove beginning and tail part of the original string only.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your solution doesn't work is because `str.strip()` only removes characters from the outsides of the string, i.e. characters on the leftmost or rightmost end of the string. So, in the case of `'foobar'`, `str.strip()` with a single character argument would only work if you wanted to remove the characters `'f'` and `'r'`.

You *could* eliminate more of the inner characters with strip, but you would need to include one of the outer characters as well.

```
>>> 'foobar'.strip('of')
'bar'
>>> 'foobar'.strip('o')
'foobar'
```

Here's how to do it by string-joining a generator expression:

```
def eliminate(s, bad_characters):
    bc = set(bad_characters)
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c not in bc)
```

Answer (score 2):

`strip` is not a correct choice for this task as it remove the characters from leading and trailing of the string, instead you can use [*str.translate*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method :

```
>>> s,l="foobar",["o","b"]
>>> s.translate(None,''.join(l))
'far'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be time consuming `using recursion`

```
def eliminate(s, seq):
    while seq:
        return eliminate(s.replace(seq.pop(),""), seq)
    return s
>>>eliminate("foobar",["o","b"])
'far'
```